# Javascript - how to stop onClick from wiping out the form/refreshing page?

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms, onclick

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<HEAD>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
<script language= "javascript">
    var array1 = new Array();
        function display1()
            {
            var guest_input = array1;
            var input1;
            var input2;
            var input3;
            input1 = document.form1.msg1.value;
            input2 = document.form1.msg2.value;
            input3 = document.form1.msg3.value;
            guest_input[0]=input1;
            guest_input[1]=input2;
            guest_input[2]=input3;
            for (var i=0; i<array1.length; i++) 
                {
                document.write("<ul><li>" +array1[i]+ "</li></ul>");
                }
            }
    </script>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<form name="form1">
    Type in msg 1 : <input type="text" name="msg1"><br>
    Type in msg 2 : <input type="text" name="msg2"><br>
    Type in msg 3 : <input type="text" name="msg3"><br>
</form>
<input type="button" value="Go!" name="button1" onclick="display1()">
</BODY>
```

This is really simple, very basic code. I just want to get this piece working before I do more to it.

I simply want the unordered list to appear below the form after the button is clicked, but why does the page refresh/wipe out the form when I click on the button? Changing it to

```
  onclick="display1(); return false;"
```

doesn't solve the problem. Thank you!

Comment: you need to append your results instead of overwriting the whole document. try appendChild instead

Comment: The page is wiped by document.write. read more at http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_write.asp

Comment: its because of document.write, its overwriting all content of the document, you can see that by view page source.

add container element like div and assign your markup to it, see the modified code below.

Answer (score 1):

You need to append the list to the form, Give your form an id and use jquery to append it

```
<form name="form1" id="fo">
    Type in msg 1 : <input type="text" name="msg1"><br>
    Type in msg 2 : <input type="text" name="msg2"><br>
    Type in msg 3 : <input type="text" name="msg3"><br>
</form>
```

your jquery

```
$('#fo').append("<ul><li>" +array1[i]+ "</li></ul>")
```

Comment: This is not a jQuery question.

Answer (score 0):

It is the browser's default functionality that it will send the form data on submitting it and refresh the page. Use `event.preventDefault()` to stop the refresh from happening:

HTML

```
<input type="button" value="Go!" name="button1" onclick="display1(event)">
```

JS

```
function display1(event)
{
  event.preventDefault();
  // do rest of the stuff here
}
```

Read this: [event.preventDefault | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault)

Answer (score 0):

Use '[appendChild](https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fjsref%2Fmet_node_appendchild.asp&ei=y-luVI-3EJfsaPHtgaAF&usg=AFQjCNF0op1f0GKYMv-RPaWCpFSx1yVlJQ&sig2=s4S7DX3kQ0HGdQ3y699vvg&bvm=bv.80185997,d.d2s)' and not '[write](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_write.asp)' because you override the HTML:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild("<ul><li>" +array1[i]+ "</li></ul>");
```

Answer (score 0):

try putting **`e.preventDefault();`** at the beginning of the function, not in the markup. Or you could also do `return false`.

```
<script language= "javascript">
    var array1 = new Array();
        function display1(e)
            {
            e.preventDefault();
            var guest_input = array1;
            var input1;
            var input2;
            var input3;
            input1 = document.form1.msg1.value;
            input2 = document.form1.msg2.value;
            input3 = document.form1.msg3.value;
            guest_input[0]=input1;
            guest_input[1]=input2;
            guest_input[2]=input3;
            for (var i=0; i<array1.length; i++) 
                {
                document.write("<ul><li>" +array1[i]+ "</li></ul>");
                }
               // you could also **return false;** here
            }

    </script>
```

Comment: `return false` is a bad idea here. It will stop the rest of the code from executing.

Comment: Where do you plan to put `return false` exactly?

Comment: Oh, I see what you meant. Updated post. return false wasn't my answer; messing with return values when unneeded is sloppy.

Comment: Its not me. I have taken mine back.

Answer (score 0):

its because of document.write, its overwriting all content of the document, you can see that by view page source.

add container element like div and assign your markup to it, see the modified code below.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <HEAD>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" language= "javascript">
        var array1 = new Array();
        function display1() {
            var guest_input = array1;
            var input1;
            var input2;
            var input3;
            input1 = document.form1.msg1.value;
            input2 = document.form1.msg2.value;
            input3 = document.form1.msg3.value;
            guest_input[0] = input1;
            guest_input[1] = input2;
            guest_input[2] = input3;
            var xx="";
            for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
                xx = xx + "<ul><li>" + array1[i] + "</li></ul>";
            }
            document.getElementById("listcontainer").innerHTML=xx;
            return false;
        }
        </script>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
    <form name="form1">
        Type in msg 1 : <input type="text" name="msg1"><br>
        Type in msg 2 : <input type="text" name="msg2"><br>
        Type in msg 3 : <input type="text" name="msg3"><br>
        <input type="button" value="Go!" name="button1" onclick="return display1();">
    </form>
        <div id="listcontainer"></div>
    </BODY>
     </html>
```